# Hosting Django web application on IIS error

Tags: django, iis, web-hosting

My organization has implemented a web application in Django, and we need to host it on a Windows system. We are using Django 3.2.8 and Python 3.8.8.

The Django project is currently stored here:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CED_HRAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="Python FastCGI" path="\*" verb="*" modules="FastCGIModule" scriptProcessor="c:\python38\python.exe|c:\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="base.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CED_HRAP" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="CED_HRAP.wsgi.application" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="CED_HRAP.settings" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Our settings.py file is located at

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CED_HRAP\CED_HRAP\settings.py

We are currently seeing this error message:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
> the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and
> directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

How should we configure the default documents in the web.config file so that it links to Django's internal routing (urls.py)?

We followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject
(youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APCQ15YqqQ0)

You can see that the web.config file in the above repository does not have any default documents specified. We added them to web.config in an effort to resolve the current error.

Have also looked at several other tutorials and documents on this process, but have not been able to resolve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because the website doesn't have the Directory Browsing feature enabled. Also, the default document isn't configured. To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods:

**Method 1: Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS**

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do it, select Start, select Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then select OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then select the website that you want to change.
3. In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
4. In the Actions pane, select Enable.

**Method 2: Add a default document**

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do it, select Start, select Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then select OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then select the website  that you want to change.
3. In the Features view, double-click Default Document.
4. In the Actions pane, select Enable.
5. In the File Name box, type the name of the default document, and then select OK.

Comment: Hi @samwu,

We have enabled directory browsing, but that didn’t yield the results we were looking for. The result is a directory listing menu of the Django project files, which is not what we want. When navigating to localhost, we would like to see the main application landing page which is not currently displayed.

Comment: We have tried to set the default document, however Django doesn’t have a typical aspx/html file that will display like the default page does.  We have tried to configure the default page, however IIS doesn’t have the ability to reference to a page in a sub folder in a way that would make the site viewable or functional.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: We were able to resolve the problem by changing the static folder into an application. The IIS component of it appears to be resolved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you found were actually broken (missing details) and not recommended (wfastcgi was deprecated).

If you revert all changes related to FastCGI and start cleanly with HttpPlatformHandler, you will see how smooth the experience is,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\python.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" arguments=".\mysite\manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Python/Django still takes care of everything including static files, and IIS/HttpPlatformHandler just passes requests on.

More details can be found from [my blog post](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/).